# Add a health check in Startup.Configure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We want to standardize health checks across our .NET Core APIs, and we thought an easy way would be to install a NuGet package which contains something we could add in the Startup file like so.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseHealthCheck(env.EnvironmentName, env.ApplicationName, "/myHealthCheckUrl");

        // And all the rest of the app.UseSomethings.
    }
```

And now if someone hits `myapp.com/myHealthCheckUrl`, they will get back a message saying something like `myAppName is alive in myEnvironmentName.`

I don't even know the right terms to use to Google for an answer. How would we go about doing this? Swashbuckle does [something similar with UseSwaggerUi](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/Application/SwaggerUIBuilderExtensions.cs#L25), but that calls `app.UseFileServer` and delivers a modified HTML page. Would this be the way to handle it, or is there a more lightweight option available? Again, we want this to have minimal impact in the rest of each API, so we're trying to avoid controller actions in the app itself.

Comment: It looks like what I want is some sort of Middleware as defined on this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

Comment: look into [Microsoft.Extensions.HealthChecks](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/master/src/BuildingBlocks/HealthChecks/src/Microsoft.Extensions.HealthChecks) If you find it as something that do more that you need, you can implement your own simple middleware, using code as tutorial.

Comment: You could start with simple [health-check-middleware](https://github.com/schwamster/health-check-middleware) package.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov Actually that is almost exactly what we were thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments on the question, what we were looking for was to provide a `Middleware`. The far simplest way to do this is by adding this piece of code into the `Configure` method, and that is what we decided to go with.

```
app.Map("/HealthCheck", a =>
{
    a.Run(async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{env.ApplicationName} is alive in {env.EnvironmentName}");
    });
});
```

Since that specifically does NOT answer the question of creating a way to do this in a NuGet package, here is how you would do it in an extensions class.

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gives a happy little response when someone makes a request to healthCheckUrl
    /// </summary>
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHealthCheck(this IApplicationBuilder app, string environmentName, string applicationName, string healthCheckUrl)
    {
        app.Map(healthCheckUrl, a =>
        {
            a.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{applicationName} is alive in environmentName");
            });
        });
        return app;
    }
}
```

And then call it with

```
app.UseHealthCheck(env.EnvironmentName, env.ApplicationName, "/myHealthCheckUrl");
```

in the `Startup.Configure` method.